# DefinedTypes is returning System Runtime Type

Tags: c#

See this screenshot

[image: [img]]

It shows that all the defined types are `RuntimeType`, I then use `myType.IsAssignableFrom(definedType)` and it never returns `true`.

This is understandable as it is `RuntimeType` but how do I get the actual type from it.

```
public static List<T> GetAllDerivedTypes<T>(this Assembly assembly)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var isInterface = type.IsInterface;
    var name = type.Name;

    if (!isInterface)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not an interface type");
    }

    List<object> types = new List<object>();
    foreach (var definedType in assembly.DefinedTypes)
    {
        var isAssignableFrom = definedType.IsAssignableFrom(type);

        var interfaces = definedType.ImplementedInterfaces.Where(x => x.Name == name);

        if (isAssignableFrom)
        {
            types.Add(definedType);
        }
    }

    return types.Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

I can easily reduce this down to a single `Linq` statement but I've blown it up so I can see what is going wrong. It will never return all the derived types of `T` where `T : interface`.

Comment: Looks like you're using `IsAssignableFrom` the wrong way. Try `type.IsAssignableFrom(definedType);` But even after that your method won't work, because you're trying to cast `TypeInfo` to `T` by calling `Cast<T>` on `types`. That's not going to work.

Comment: Thanks @MarcinJuraszek was indeed my issues

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I was doing two things wrong.

- Not using `IsAssignableFrom` correctly
- using `Cast<T>` when they are types and not instantiated objects

Solution:

```
    public static List<T> GetAllDerivedTypes<T>(this Assembly assembly)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var isInterface = type.IsInterface;

        if (!isInterface)
        {
            throw new Exception("Not an interface type");
        }

        return assembly
                    .DefinedTypes
                    .Where(x => type.IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface)
                    .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
                    .Cast<T>()
                    .ToList();
    }
```

Comment: This is bound to fail for types which don’t have a public default constructor (or abstract types even). Also, don’t self-answer your question when you have nothing new to add to existing answers. You should [upvote and accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) helpful answers instead.

Comment: This is helpful. On separate note I know all the derived types of this interface have default constructors or they **should** have. So for **my** situation this is perfect. I will be up voting other answers, but this is the correct solution.

Comment: Even if you know that *your* types have a default constructor, you should still consider adding an addtional check—or at least check for exceptions (e.g. `MissingMethodException`)—to make sure that really all types you find allow instantiation using a default constructor. After all, your interface cannot enfore this.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the method call the wrong way round. Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx . `definedType.IsAssignableFrom(type)` will return true if type is derived from definedType, you want the other way round.

From the docs:

```
public virtual bool IsAssignableFrom(Type c)
```

Will return true if any of the following are true:

- c and the current instance represent the same type.
- c is derived either directly or indirectly from the current instance.
- The current instance is an interface that c implements.
- c is a generic type parameter, and the current instance represents one of the constraints of c.
- c represents a value type, and the current instance represents Nullable (Nullable(Of c) in Visual Basic).

So change your call to:

```
var isAssignableFrom = type.IsAssignableFrom(definedType);
```

Comment: type is an interface and I want to see if definedType is derived from it, this is what you are saying?

Answer (score -1):

Chris already replied to the fact that you are using `IsAssignableFrom` in the wrong order. You want to call `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(definedType)` in order to check whether you can assign an object of type `definedType` to a variable of type `T`.

But there is also another problem with your code, which I have reduced to this one that hopefully highlights it:

```
public static List<T> GetAllDerivedTypes<T>(this Assembly assembly)
{
    // …
    List<object> types = new List<object>();
    foreach (var definedType in assembly.DefinedTypes)
    {
        // …
        types.Add(definedType);
    }

    return types.Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

`definedType` in each iteration is a `Type`, an instance of the type `Type`. So when you add it to the `types` list, you are adding *a type*.

A type however is not the same as an object that has the type of your generic type `T` (your interface). So `types.Cast<T>()` will fail because `Type` cannot be casted to your interface type `T`. Similarly, the return value of `List<T>` makes no sense since you get back a list of *types*, not a list of objects that have the type of your interface.

So you want to change it to this:

```
public static List<Type> GetAllDerivedTypes<T>(this Assembly assembly)
{
    // …
    List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
    foreach (var definedType in assembly.DefinedTypes)
    {
        // …
        types.Add(definedType);
    }

    return types;
}
```

Comment: I know that the `List<object>` is wrong and won't work, I'm fully aware, I was just shutting up the compiler. I just wanted to see why derived type wasn't working

Comment: `T` is an interface, so this will still work for this

Comment: *“so this will still work for this”* – no it won’t? It doesn’t matter if it’s an interface or not. A type is a type is a type.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying there. But anyway, the `IsAssignable` is working for me now.

Comment: I was saying that it doesn’t matter for the code whether `T` is an interface or not. The types you find would all still be `Type` objects which you cannot cast to the type `T`. Btw. I hope that you have a better reason to downvote this answer than because of my downvote of yours…